# Retrieving all documents without iterating the cursor using mongo driver

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm using the mongo driver together with NodeJs to retrieve database collections.

Here is a simple code to get all users:

```
const getUsers = async context => {
    let users = await db.collection("users");

    let result = await users.find({
        deletedAt: null
    });

    console.log(result)
    return result
};
```

The `result` is a cursor that needs to be iterated.

Is there a way to retrieve all records without the need of iterating, something like `toArray()` or `toJSON()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.toArray()` as you expect ([docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/reference/cursors/)):

> To get all documents at once, users can use the toArray method.

```
const getUsers = async context => {
    let users = await db.collection("users");

    let cursor = users.find({
        deletedAt: null
    });

    let result = await cursor.toArray();

    console.log(result)
    return result
};
```